# Can't receive UDP packets in Android app

Tags: android, udp, handler

I can only send packets with my Client.class but I can't receive packets with my Server.class. The Client and the Server are in each case two Threads. To update the `MainActivity` I use a handler. The handler works (I tested it) but not the Server.class.

```
public class Client implements Runnable {

    //@Override
    public void run() {
        do{
            try {
                    InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(Server.CLIENTIP);

                    DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket();

                    byte[] buf = ("Test").getBytes();

                    DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length,serverAddr,Server.CLIENTPORT);

                    socket.send(packet);
                }     
            catch (Exception e) {}
        }
        while(open == true);
    }
}

public class Server implements Runnable {

public static String CLIENTIP = "192.168.0.13";//send-ip
public static String SERVERIP = "10.0.0.18";//receive-ip
public static final int CLIENTPORT = 5000; //send-port
public static final int SERVERPORT = 5001; //receive-port

 //@Override
    public void run() {
        do
        {
            try {
                DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket(SERVERPORT);

                    byte[] buf = new byte[256];
                    DatagramPacket rpacket = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length);

                    socket.receive(rpacket);

                    String x = new String(rpacket.getData());
                    MainActivity.glText = x;        
                    MainActivity.mHandler.post(MainActivity.mTimer);

                } 
            catch (Exception e) {}
        }
        while(open == true);
    }
}
```

Has anyone a solution for this problem? Thanks for your answers! ;)

Answer (score 1):

You're listening on different port number than you are trying to send to if you try to use the pasted code for the communication.

You will not be able to connect the server from outside your device easily because you are binding to `localhost` address (which is default address when omitted):

```
DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket(SERVERPORT);
```

You should bind to an address that is reachable from your PC:

```
DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket(SERVERPORT02,
                        InetAddress.getByName(SERVERIP));
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. I would like to communicate as a test between android-platform and my own computer. My computer has the IP 192.168.0.13 and my andoird-platform the IP 10.0.0.18. The setting on my computer is send-port = 5001/receive port = 5000 and on my Andoird-Plattform send-port = 5000/receive-port = 5001. The Client.class is working. But i cant receive anything from the computer. What i have to change in code? thanks ;)

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the emulator?  If so you might to to forward the ports so that the emulator can receive the packets.

In order to redirect ports from host to emulator device, use the redir command with 
this format: 
redir add ::

For example, to forward UDP packet with destination port 5001 into emulator with 
the same port, you can use:
redir add udp:5001:5001

Comment: Yes, i'am using the emulator. I want to connect android-emulator with my own computer. I've use the "redir add udp:5001:5001". After that the connection between the computer and the emulator was working. I can send Informations from the android-emulator to the computer but i can't receive Informations from the computer. :( Have you any other idea?

Comment: no, don't know of any issues there.  Once we started the port forwarding it all worked for us on both ends.  What happens if you send to the same port?

Comment: nothing :( ...Now i've change everything on this way (http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/simple-udp-communication-example). But i always can't receive informations on the android-emulator. I put an Log.d("test","test") behind the s.receive(p). But it seems so that he can't reach this position. Is it right that i've on the android-emulator only to set one port (for example 5001) and on the computer (udp-test-programm) i must set two ports? What do you mean with the destination port 29392? (thanks for your answer)

Comment: @Chris sorry the port 29392 was a typo from my copy-pasting (I fixed it in the answer).  You shouldn't need to open two ports from what I remember you can use one port, you just need to set up a consistant protocol so one side is trying to receive and one is sending for each transaction.  Maybe try a simpler example that you send from the server and receive on the device (with port forwarding enabled) and make sure that works.  If that works try the opposite direction, if that works then just create a logical protocol.

Comment: @Mikelsreal: It's really nice of you that you answer me soo fast. ;) Before i try it step by step i've show me the exception. The exception is:"java.net.bindexception EADDRINUSE (address already in use)". Have you any idea?where the problem is?

Comment: What line of your code does the exception come from?  It should be visible in the logcat with the associate class.

Comment: @Mikelsreal: Ohh sorry, i've forgotten "s.close()". :(

Comment: @Mikelsreal: Unfortunately not. :( ...At first the bad news. It doesn't work with the emulator. The Problem is something like the "redir add udp:5001:5001" or other settings for the emulator. Because, it works on the mobilephone. And that are the good news. ;)

Comment: @Chris it should really work with the port forwarding, did you try maybe increasing the value for the port?  5001 is kind of low, so maybe it is being used by another application.